# Equal degree sum of two graph shows they have equal vertex degrees??

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I am looking for the answer of the question if two graphs have equal degree sum, then whether both have equal vertex degree.i.e., If $G$ has vertices $d_{i}$ and $G^{\prime}$ has vertices $d^{\prime}_{i},i=1,2,..,n$ and 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}$=$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d^{\prime}_{i}$,  can we say that $d_{1}=d^{\prime}_{1}, d_{2}=d^{\prime}_{2},...,d_{n}=d^{\prime}_{n}$

Comment: No, why would that be the case?

Comment: @DonThousand. In case of self-complementary graph this is true, but do we have some other graph with this condition. ??

Comment: So your question isn't "is this true?", but rather "are there nice classes of graphs for which this is true?" Is that right? Please clarify.

Comment: I just know about self-complemetry graph. Still we have any other class with this condition?

Comment: The  degree sequence for a 4 vertex self-complementary graph is 2,2,1,1. and the complement has the same sequence, and so their sum is equal.

Answer (score 1):

Counter examples are easily generated. Eg see below.

[image]